# can not set content type to 'application/json' angular js 2

Tags: angularjs, angular, http-post

I am trying to set content type to json for my http post call in angular js 2 service.
but it is not setting to the json causing getting null values in the api parameter

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
@Injectable()
export class DeviceService {
public headers: Headers;

constructor(private http:Http) {
    this.headers = new Headers();
    this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
}

/*getAllUsers service to get data(users) from file or database*/
getDevice() {
    return this.http.get('assets/api/device.json').map(
        response => response.json()
    );
}

save(model) 
{
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:14/someapi/method',
        JSON.stringify(model),{headers: this.headers})
        .map(response => response.json());
}
```

But when making post call it always show content type as 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' in firebug console.[image]

Comment: Looks like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35032465/angular2-http-post-headers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to import the `Headers` class:

```
import {Http, Headers} from 'angular2/http';
```

So you don't see any errors but the headers aren't included in the request...